# Loadbalancing python webserver in kubernetes pods

Tags: python-3.x, docker, kubernetes

I was going through Docker and Kubernetes . I want to create two Python web servers and need to access them using public URL and these requests should be balanced between two servers.

I created one Python server and initially deployed that with Docker containers and all this I'm doing using AWS ec2 instance so when I tried to send a request I used ec2publicip:port. This is working which means I created one web server and similarly I will do the same for the second server.

My question is If I deploy this with Kubernetes - Is there any way to do load balancing the Python web servers within the pod. If so, can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create two replicas of the pod via a kubernetes [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) and create a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) of type [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) an ELB on AWS is automatically provisioned.Then whenever a request comes to the ELB on AWS it will distribute the traffic to the replicas of the pod. With a loadbalancer type service you get advanced load balancing capabilities at layer 7. Without a loadbalancer type service or an ingress you get round robin load balancing at layer 4 offered by kube proxy.

Problem with loadbalancer type service is that it will create new ELB for each service which is costly. So I recommend using ingress controller such as [Nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) and expose the Nginx Ingress controller via a single [loadbalancer](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/deploy/static/provider/cloud) on AWS. Then create [ingress resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource) and use path or host based routing to send traffic to pods behind a clusterIP type service.